# Get object from JSON array of objects within array of objects, using PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

Two JSON files contain JSON objects, one JSON file contains array of objects within array of objects.
File orders.json:

```
{
    "orders": [
        {
            "address": null,
            "createdAt": "2023-09-13T12:17:32Z",
            "nmId": 1715161312, *ID of product's card
            "chrtId": 28173947  *ID of product's size
        },
        ...
        ]
}
```

File cards.json:

```
[
    {       
        "nmID": 1715161312,
        "vendorCode": "22SP-456P-nero",
        "sizes": [
            {
                "techSize": "2",
                "chrtID": 28173946,
                "price": 900
            },
            {
                "techSize": "3",
                "chrtID": 28173947,
                "price": 700
            }
          ]
    },...
```

I need to append "techSize", "price", information from cards file, as well as "vendorCode". I was trying to do it this way:

```
// Iterate over the orders in new_orders_with_tags.json
foreach ($newOrdersData['orders'] as &$order) {
    // Find the corresponding card in cards.json based on chrtId
    $card = array_filter($cardsPlusData, function ($item) use ($order) {
        return $item['chrtID'] == $order['chrtID'];
    });

    // If a matching card is found, extract the required data
    if (!empty($card)) {
        $card = reset($card);
        $order['vendorCode'] = $card['vendorCode'];
        $order['techSize'] = $card['sizes'][0]['techSize'];
        $order['price'] = $card['sizes'][0]['price'];
    }
}
```

For some reason I cannot reach chrtId and cannot get it why. Any ideas?
It could be a wrong way of doing this. Should I find "ID of product's card" first and then find corresponding size?

Comment: It should be `nmID` instead of `chrtID` in your `array_filter` closure.

Comment: Alright, what else do I need to add to get specific techsize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your array_filter as below:

```
$card = array_filter($cardsPlusData, function ($item) use ($order) {
        return $item['nmID'] == $order['nmID'];
    });
```

To get specific `techsize` you need to run another filter for `card['size']`:

```
$orderSize = array_filter($card['size'], function ($size) use ($order) {
        return $size['chartID'] == $order['chrtID'];
    });
```

Now inside `$orderSize` you will have a single result as below:

```
{
                "techSize": "2",
                "chrtID": 28173946,
                "price": 900
            },
```

And you can get techSize

```
$orderSize =  $orderSize['techSize']; // check if not empty first
```